# Generalising an SQL table lookup function using exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL function:

```
create function [dbo].[LookUpAnonymiseString](@string varchar(500), @tableSize int)
returns varchar(500)
as
begin
       DECLARE @output varchar(500)
       SELECT @output = Value FROM AnonymisationLookup.dbo.Forename WHERE AnonymisationLookup.dbo.Forename.ID = ABS(CHECKSUM(@string)) % @tableSize
       return @output
end
go
```

I believe this function works fine, it takes an input string and int representing the size of a look up table (containing all available strings). I then hash the input string into an index to look up the table, returning the value at that index for an output string.

I want to generalise the function so the name of the table can be passed in and used in the query, rather than the hardcoded "Forename" table.

I've tried the following, but SQL complains and says "Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function."

```
create function [dbo].[LookUpAnonymiseString](@string varchar(500), @tableName varchar(128), @tableSize int)
returns varchar(500)
as
begin
    declare @output varchar(500)
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
    set @sql = N'select @output = Value from AnonymisationLookup.dbo.'+quotename(@tableName)+' where AnonymisationLookup.dbo.'+quotename(@tableName)+'.ID = abs(checksum(@string)) % @tableSize'
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@output nvarchar(max) out', @output out
    return @output
end
go
```

Comment: You can not execute a stored procedure from a function. Replacing the function with a stored procedure may be the solution.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Might look into these

Answer (score 1):

Your first query "sort of" works.  It only works if there are no gaps in the ids -- and it is pretty easy for ids to have gaps (even `identity` columns).  So a safer method is:

```
   DECLARE @output varchar(500);

   SELECT TOP 1 @output = Value
   FROM AnonymisationLookup.dbo.Forename f
   WHERE F.ID >= ABS(CHECKSUM(@string)) % @tableSize
   ORDER BY F.ID;

   return @output;
```

Then, your goal to pass in the table cannot be done in a function (except in a really complicated, abstruse way).  Hence, you really cannot do what you want to do.  You *can* use dynamic SQL in a stored procedure, but that cannot be used directly in a function.

Comment: I've given you an upvote for the comments, but my tables are produced on the fly so I don't think ID will be an issue. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @dahui, have you tried this answer (a stored procedure that builds the desired SQL statement and executes using `sp_executesql`) or are you stuck with that?

Comment: @DanGuzman . . . You can't call a stored procedure in a stored function . . . unless you go out to the operating system and connect back to SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, agreed. My comment was in response to another comment that I no longer see.